# How to parse a string to retrieve the words in the string in variables using shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a command which when executed gives following outputs

```
$ cleartool pwv
Working directory view: abhijeet_trialProj_r2.4-phase1_ba_abhijeet_branch
Set view: abhijeet_trialProj_r2.4-phase1_ba_abhijeet_branch

$ cleartool pwv
Working directory view: ** NONE ** 
Set view: abhijeet_trialProj_r2.4-phase1_ba_abhijeet_branch

$ ct pwv 
Working directory view: ** NONE **
Set view: ** NONE **
```

I am using this command "cleartool pwv" in a shell script.

```
view_used=`cleartool pwv`
```

Thus $view_used is assigned the string  "Working directory view: ** NONE ** Set view: abhijeet_trialProj_r2.4-phase1_ba_abhijeet_branch"

I need to retrieve two values from $view_used such that

working_dir_view="**** NONE ****" or "**abhijeet_trialProj_r2.4-phase1_ba_abhijeet_branch**"

set_view = "**** NONE ****" or "**abhijeet_trialProj_r2.4-phase1_ba_abhijeet_branch**"

Could some body help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you have awk,

```
var=$(cleartool pwv |awk -F":" '/Working directory view/{
 t=$2
}/Set view/{s=$2}
END{
  print t,s
}
')
set -- $var
echo $1
echo $2
```

with shell(bash) scripting

```
while IFS=":" read -r a b
do
  case "$a" in
   *"Working directory"* ) w="$b";;
   *"Set view"* ) s="$b";;
  esac
done <"file1"
echo "$w"
echo "$s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're always of that format (two lines, same order, colon separator):

```
working_view="$(ct pwv | head -1 | sed 's/[^:]*: //')"
set_view="$(ct pwv | tail -1 | sed 's/[^:]*: //')"
```

If you *must* use `${view_used}` (in other words, if you don't want to call the ClearCase tool twice), simply substitute it as follows:

```
working_view="$(echo "${view_used}" | head -1 | sed 's/[^:]*: //')"
set_view="$(echo "${view_used}" | tail -1 | sed 's/[^:]*: //')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have awk:

```
working_dir_view=$(cleartool pwv | awk '
  /Working directory view/ {gsub(/.*:\s+/,"");print $0}
')
set_view=$(cleartool pwv | awk '
  /Set view/ {gsub(/.*:\s+/,"");print $0}
')
```

If you really want to do it from a string in the variable:

```
working_dir_view=$(echo $view_used | awk '
  /Working directory view/ {gsub(/.*:\s+/,"");print $0}
')
set_view=$(echo $view_used | awk '
  /Set view/ {gsub(/.*:\s+/,"");print $0}
')
```

In a script file it's probably more maintainable to refactor them as a function:

```
getView(){
    echo $2 | awk "/$1 view/ {gsub(/^.*:[ \t]+/,\"\");print\$0}"
}
```

So now you can do:

```
working_dir_view=`getView "Working directory" "$view_used"`
set_view=`getView Set "$view_used"`
```